# How can I get colored output from Maven and SBT on Windows?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

Is there a way to get colorized output from Maven and SBT on Windows?

Answer (score -1):

I get colorized output from SBT on Windows with I use it with ENSIME in Emacs.  So try using Emacs.

Comment: I use Intellij Idea. Back to the days when I was using VI, I cannot think about how to code, all my heads are VI commands, I guess Emacs couldn't suit for me as well. :)